# D3.js Uncaught TypeError:

Tags: php, html, d3.js

I'm kinda new to D3.js and I'm trying to make line graph using json data that I get from MySQL database. But I get this error:

Error with php json

[image]

Also tried to make .json file with data that I get from getdata.php file, but then I get this error:

Error with seperate json file

[image]

php code to get json data from database:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Database data to json format</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "**********", "*********", "ismanieji_vazonai");

        $sql = "SELECT Data, Temperatura FROM parametrai";

        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        $json_array = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $json_array[] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode($json_array);

        /*
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($json_array);
        echo '</pre>';
        */

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

html code:

```
        <body>

            <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

            <script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.json("getdata.php", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});

</script>       
        </body>
```

This is how json format data looks like that i get:

```
[{"Data":"2018-12-19 18:06:54","Temperatura":"24.1"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:07:00","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:07:05","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:07:10","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:07:16","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:07:21","Temperatura":"24.1"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:07:26","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:07:32","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:07:37","Temperatura":"23.8"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:07:42","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:07:47","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:07:53","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:07:58","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:08:03","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:08:09","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:08:14","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:08:34","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:08:54","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:09:15","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:09:35","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:09:55","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:10:16","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:10:36","Temperatura":"24.2"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:10:56","Temperatura":"24.1"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:11:17","Temperatura":"24.1"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:11:37","Temperatura":"24.1"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:11:57","Temperatura":"24.1"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:12:17","Temperatura":"24"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:12:38","Temperatura":"24"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:12:58","Temperatura":"24"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:13:18","Temperatura":"24"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:13:39","Temperatura":"24"},
 {"Data":"2018-12-19 18:13:59","Temperatura":"24"}]
```

Comment: you chart `data`-vs-`close` but you supply `Data`-vs-`Temperatura`

Comment: You also need to remove all the html code in your `getdata.php` script, and send appropriate headers for Json with `header('Content-Type: application/json');` at the top of the script.